# Microsoft.office.interop.excel is very slow while updating the PageSetup

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

Earlier I had a same issue(slow), while updating the data into excel Rows, that time i used appl.screenupdating =false. it gets 200% speed and increased the speed while updating the excel rows.
but, still it is slow while updating PageSetup.
Here is my code, could you please help me on this.

```
  ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = false; 
  sheettExcel.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "Test"; 
  ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
```

Comment: How slow is slow?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to optimize your code you need:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual

[YOUR CODE HERE]

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

The [Application.Calculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Calculation) property allows setting an `XlCalculation` value that represents the calculation mode. See [How Excel determines the current mode of calculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/current-mode-of-calculation) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Eugene Astafiev, will try this too.

Comment: Eugene Astafiev - any comment is available for PowerPoint and word like this? Thanks for your support.